# How to compile a list of other lists by checkbox?

Tags: arrays, list, google-sheets, filter, checkbox

I'm trying to write a cell formula which can essentially create a single playlist of songs.

Currently the songs are grouped by decade, but I'd like to be able to see a single list of everything that has been ticked.

I tried an array formula, but it only returned the first ticked song. Plus not sure how to make the array formula include the adjacent lists.

[image: Attempt 1]

I tried a FILTER function, it works for one list of songs, but I don't know how to get it to append the other lists on the end.

[image: Attempt 2]

Could I use a QUERY function? Not sure how though.

Many thanks!

[image: Song lists]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"LIST"; FILTER({C:C; F:F}; {B:B; E:E}=TRUE)}
```

Answer (score 1):

awesome question! You were super close in your filter example, one more filter in your array would've done it :)

Example Image:

[image: Image Link because I'm still a stack noob :D]

Example Formula:
`={"LIST"; FILTER(C:C, B:B=TRUE); FILTER(F:F, E:E=TRUE)}`